# PHP count sum of several columns based on array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count

I want to sum some columns together based on a array. Previous I did it like this:

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT idnummer, productnaam,($kolommen[0]+$kolommen[1]+$kolommen[2]+$kolommen[3]+$kolommen[4]+$kolommen[5]+$kolommen[6]+$k
olommen[7]+$kolommen[8]+$kolommen[9]+$kolommen[10]+$kolommen[11]+$kolommen[12]+$kolommen[13]+$
kolommen[14]) AS total FROM wasmachine ORDER BY total DESC, prijs LIMIT 0, 5") or 
trigger_error("Fout in de query");
```

But I think this is not the right way to do it, because I want it dynamically. I want to use the full array like

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT idnummer, productnaam,($kolommen) AS total FROM wasmachine ORDER BY total DESC, prijs LIMIT 0, 5") or 
trigger_error("Fout in de query");
```

This is my database example:

```
idnummer | productnaam | v1a2 | v2a1 | v3a2
1        |  test 1     |   1  |   2  |   1
2        |  test 2     |   1  |   2  |   1
3        |  test 3     |   1  |   2  |   1
4        |  test 4     |   1  |   2  |   1
```

I tried it with **array_sum** and **count** but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: $kolommen is a php array. How does this link to any row from the table? Or is it a constant?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your **$kolommen** array contains names of all rows you need to sum?
Then you can write your query this way:

```
"SELECT idnummer, productnaam,(".join('+', $kolommen).") AS total FROM wasmachine ORDER BY total DESC, prijs LIMIT 0, 5"
```

Function **join** will *glue* elements of the array with string '+'.

Your can use **implode** as alias function of **join**, if you wish.

Comment: Hi Oleg,

Thanks so much for your response! I just tested this:  (".implode('+', $kolommen).") and this works. Is this the right way or is join better? Please let me know! Thanks! Kind regards, Mark

Comment: No difference. **implode** and **join** works exactly the same. It's a matter of taste.